# removing column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
                  Date  Year  Month  Day Security Trade  Value
0  2011-01-10 00:00:00  2011      1   10     AAPL   Buy   1500
1  2011-01-13 00:00:00  2011      1   13     AAPL  Sell   1500
```

When I write this to csv, an extra column is created at the start of the file:

```
,Date,Year,Month,Day,Security,Trade,Value
0,2011-01-10 00:00:00,2011,1,10,AAPL,Buy,1500
1,2011-01-13 00:00:00,2011,1,13,AAPL,Sell,1500
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

The "extra column" is the index.  You can suppress this by passing `index=None`, for example:

```
>>> df
    A
0  10
1  20
2  30
>>> df.to_csv("out.csv")
>>> !cat out.csv
,A
0,10
1,20
2,30
>>> df.to_csv("out.csv", index=None)
>>> !cat out.csv
A
10
20
30
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I have tried that already , and i am getting the following error.... df = pd.read_csv(input_file, index=None)
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: `df.to_csv` isn't the same thing as `pd.read_csv`.  `df.to_csv` writes the dataframe `df` to a csv file, `pd.read_csv` is for reading a csv file in.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The index = None,  is worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DSM the docs state that `index` takes a boolean so shouldn't it be `False` rather than `None` even though that does work? I've always used `False` because of this

Comment: Hi, i have one more question. New to stackoverflow. and i didnt get the hang of formatting and not able to get get the question uploaded.